# PostgreSQL query inconsistency

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, wikipedia

I am trying to execute this SQL command:

```
SELECT page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace, COUNT(*) 
    FROM page, pagelinks
    WHERE 
        (page.page_namespace <=3 OR page.page_namespace = 12 
            OR page.page_namespace = 13
        ) 
        AND 
        (pagelinks.pl_namespace <=3 OR pagelinks.pl_namespace = 12 
            OR pagelinks.pl_namespace = 13
        )
        AND 
        (page.page_is_redirect = 0)
        AND 
        pagelinks.pl_from = page.page_id 
    GROUP BY (page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace) 
;
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
    ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type record
    HINT:  Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.

    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record
    SQL state: 42883
    Hint: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.
```

I have tried adding : *ORDER BY (page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace) ASC* to the end of the query without success.

UPDATE:

I also tried this:

```
SELECT page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace, COUNT(*) 
    FROM page, pagelinks
    WHERE pagelinks.pl_from = page.page_id 
    GROUP BY (page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace) 
;
```

But I still get the same error.

Thx

Comment: Post your schema and a sample SQL data file, otherwise, it is not easy to see what's going on.

Comment: [3]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Mediawiki-database-schema.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't checked any documentation but the fact that you have your `GROUP BY` expression in parentheses looks unusual to me.  What happens if you don't use parentheses here?

Comment: I just tested and, yes, you're right, the parenthesis produce this strange error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert, but my understanding of that message is that PostgreSQL compains about not being able to handle either `page.page_namespace <=3` or `pagelinks.pl_namespace <=3`. To make a comparison like that you need to have an order defined and maybe one of these fields is not a standard numerical field. Or maybe there is some issue with integer vs. floating point -- e.g. the question if "3.0 = 3" isn't really that easy to answer since the floating point representation of 3.0 is most likely not exactly 3.

All just guesswork, but I'm pretty sure those two `<=`s are your problem.

Comment: as you can see from my update, that wasn't the problem. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not know the schema (*) you use but the error message seems clear. One of your columns is of type [RECORD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) and there is no operator to order RECORD.But some parts of your query like <= requires such an ordering operator. Using ORDER BY is unlikely to help since the crux of the problem is the lack of an operator to order...

(*) From your other questions, I assume your schema is Wikipedia page dump in http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz Correct?

Comment: Well, as I said, post the DDL (CREATE TABLE requests) and a sample of the data file. Otherwise, that's too difficult to debug.

Comment: Actually, none of the columns were of type RECORD. what is that supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: actually, your link does not seem to be working for me AKA page will not load. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

i has some error.
but i found this page, 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
it's easy, you must group without brackets
for example:

GROUP BY (page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace) 
the correct is
 GROUP BY page.page_namespace, pagelinks.pl_namespace

greetings!!

Comment: This has been cleared two years ago, and it is still true. Your answer doesn't add anything.